# Azure function - request image from 3d party then send image to requestor without saving to local directory

Tags: image, azure, function, httpresponse

I've found lots of questions about downloading images and as my code shows that is what I ended up doing. However that is not the behavior I want. I just want it to return the image directly.

```
using System.Net;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using System.IO;

public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Run(HttpRequest req, ILogger log, string data) 
{
    log.LogInformation("start function...");
    string qrData = $"{data}";//req.Query["id"];
    string QrGeneratorUrl = "https://api.qrserver.com/v1/create-qr-code/?size=100x100&data="+ qrData;
    log.LogInformation("QrUrl= " + QrGeneratorUrl);

    var filename = "temp.png";
    var filePath = Path.Combine(@"d:\home\site\wwwroot\QrGeneratorTest\"+filename);

    WebClient myWebClient = new WebClient();
    myWebClient.DownloadFile(QrGeneratorUrl, filePath);

    var response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
    var fileStream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open);
    response.Content = new StreamContent(fileStream);
    return response;
}
```

I've tried converting the image to a byte stream and adding the stream to the response content, I've tried putting the image data directly as string content... nothing seems to work - it only transmits the image if it is a local file and I add it to the response via fileStream.  Does someone know how I can get it to just put the response I get into the response I am returning? Or explain why it can't be done?  This is functionality that exists in a web app that we are trying the move into a function and the web app is able to pass the content along without saving it. Using a byte stream. But I can't seem to replicate that in the function.

There are 2 reasons we are not calling qr server directly
1) it's a 3d party site so it could go down and we need to be able to swap it out for a new provider from one location.
2) we need to build the url so it has not parameters (?p=1&q=2&r=3...) as this is going into an email and having a bunch of parameters often tags the email as junk. With Azure (as with our web app) we can build the url like this:  /getImage/1/2/3 which is less likely to be tagged as spam

any insight would be appreciated!!

//*******************//
ANSWER
here is my final code. I think the issue was Stream vs MemoryStream... In any case here is the full code:

```
#r "Newtonsoft.Json"

using System.Net;
using System;
using System.Web;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using System.Text;

public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Run(HttpRequest req, ILogger log, string data) 
{
    log.LogInformation("start function...");
    string qrData = $"{data}";
    //string qrData = DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString();
    string QrGeneratorUrl = "https://api.qrserver.com/v1/create-qr-code/?size=100x100&qzone=2&data="+ qrData;

    //get the QR image from 3d party api
    var httpWebRequest = WebRequest.Create(QrGeneratorUrl);
    var httpResponse = await httpWebRequest.GetResponseAsync();

    //put 3d party response into function response
    Stream ms = httpResponse.GetResponseStream(); //new MemoryStream(bytes);
    var result = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
    result.Content = new StreamContent(ms);
    result.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("image/png");

    return result;
}
```

Comment: I've been trying various ways to use the file download - async, sync, same name, different name. But they all fail when doing performance testing. If the process is async then the next request fails because it can't access the file being used by current process. If it's sync then I assume it just doesn't run at all. Typically for 100 requests in 1 minute I get 10 successful requests. Ideally I dont want to deal with files at all - I just want to pass along the response I get from the 3d party...  The function will be called from <img src="function" > and should return the required image.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you want to download the image to stream and just return it(If use browser send the request, show the image in the browser, If I get it wrong please let me know). If this is your purpose you could refer to my below code, I download the image from blob and return it to `FileContentResult`.

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob;
using System.DrawingCore;

namespace FunctionApp72
{
    public static class Function1
    {
        [FunctionName("Function1")]
        public static async Task<IActionResult> RunAsync(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,
            ILogger log)
        {
            log.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");

            CloudStorageAccount blobAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("AzureWebJobsStorage"));
            CloudBlobClient blobClient = blobAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();

            CloudBlobContainer blobContainer = blobClient.GetContainerReference("test");
            CloudBlockBlob cloudBlockBlob = blobContainer.GetBlockBlobReference("test.jpg");
            MemoryStream streamIn = new MemoryStream();
            await cloudBlockBlob.DownloadToStreamAsync(streamIn);

            Image originalImage = Bitmap.FromStream(streamIn);
            return new FileContentResult(ImageToByteArray(originalImage), "image/jpeg");

        }

        private static byte[] ImageToByteArray(Image image)
        {
            ImageConverter converter = new ImageConverter();
            return (byte[])converter.ConvertTo(image, typeof(byte[]));
        }
    }
}
```

And I deploy it to azure It still could return the image.

[image]

Comment: thanks!  I'm trying to implement - just having issues with my references and stuff. Once I get that sorted I will post my code and update you. Might take a couple days :)

Comment: I can't get it to reference System.DrawingCore or any other drawing package. But before I continue fighting with it can you see if you can get it to return an image directly from here: https://api.qrserver.com/v1/create-qr-code/?size=100x100&data=123456 .....  I don't want to save the image to a blob, or a file or anything, I want to dynamically lookup the image at that url and return it to the user.

Comment: Yes I could. And I just use blob to do a test, not save it to blob.

Comment: can you paste the code you used in the function to make it display the qr code directly from that url?  I'm not seeing how I can swap out 'blob' for 'url'